# How to build a URL with a variable for importing daily data in Google Sheets (using Apps Script)?

Tags: api, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to automatically scrape data on a daily basis with the IMPORTDATA-function in Google Sheets. I am using an URL-based API. My problem is that in the structure of the URL a certain date has to be inserted. I do not know how to turn the date into a variable so that the URL automatically changes every day.

The URL for yesterday's data is: https://www.benzinpreis.de/statistik.phtml?o=4&so=b.order_total&cnt=50&mystatart=LKR&mystat=DAY13.11.2022+00%3A00%3A00

My code now looks like this:

```
function TagesdurchschnittDeutschland() {
  let yesterday = new Date()
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TagesdurchschnittDeutschland'))
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate()
.setFormula('=IMPORTHTML("https://www.benzinpreis.de/statistik.phtml?o=4&so=b.order_total&cnt=50&mystatart=LKR&mystat=DAY' + yesterday.getDate() + '.' + yesterday.getMonth() + '.' + yesterday.getFullYear() + '+00%3A00%3A00"; "table"; 5)');

}
```

Comment: and you want the content of the day to replace the content of yesterday or to keep an history of it ? In pure Google Sheets formula you have ways to display the date in the format you want. In Apps Script as well.

Comment: @ValLeNain Both of it. In one sheet, I want to display only yesterday's data. Therefore I would like to create the URL for the IMPORTDATA-function with a variable. In another sheet, I want to keep track of last month's data by setting a daily trigger to add the data currently displayed in the first sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return the URL for yesterday. It is dependent on the timezone defined for your Apps Script, which [you can change](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getscripttimezone) in the global settings of your script.

```
function makeYesterdayUrl() {
  let yesterday = new Date()
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
  return 'https://www.benzinpreis.de/statistik.phtml?o=4&so=b.order_total&cnt=50&mystatart=LKR&mystat=DAY'
    + yesterday.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0') 
    + '.' 
    + (yesterday.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0') 
    + '.' 
    + yesterday.getFullYear()
    + '+00%3A00%3A00'
}
```

Note to myself, never forget that `getMonth` starts at 0 (for January), not 1... ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth))

Comment: Thank you very much, @ValLeNain! It works, but only partially. I'm afraid. If I integrate your code, the date in the URL is not 13/11/2022 but 13/10/2022 and I don't understand why.

Comment: can you put a `console.log(yesterday)` just before the line `yesterday.setDate...` and just after this line, and tell me what it displays when you run the function ?

Comment: It says:  Mon Nov 14 2022 13:49:20 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

Comment: the first one or the second one ? there are two `console.log` to insert :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just read half of it :D 

It says: 
13:53:31 Info Mon Nov 14 2022 13:53:31 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
13:53:31 Info Sun Nov 13 2022 13:53:31 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

Comment: so the two Dates are correct, I'm very surprised that they're not well displayed in the URL, have you copied the exact version I made ?

Comment: Yes, I integrated it via copy and paste into my function. As I said, everything works fine, just that it gives out the data for the wrong month.

Comment: could you please update your initial post with the full code then, so I'll try it as it is on your side. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I've just pasted it into my initial request.

Comment: sorry my bad it's me. I forgot that `getMonth` starts at month 0 (and not 1). Also for days and months like '1', '2', '3', the new version will turn into '01', '02', '03'. If you don't want this behaviour, remode the `padStart` (code updated in my post)

Comment: Yay, now it works! Thank you so much - that was my first request here in Stackoverflow. I wouldn't have thought to get help so quickly. Best wishes from Germany :)

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could validate the post as the answer to your problem (green tick on the left). Thanks!